# Update Angular just by updating package version: any consequences?

Tags: angular

What potential problem I could have if instead of going "traditional" way to update via https://update.angular.io/ I'll just update version in package.json and run *npm install*?

As I understand, private npm registries are unable to perform it via update command.

If I update packages manually, and build my project with no errors: is that indication that all goes well? Or is it hidden pitfalls somewhere?

Comment: It is possible that dependencies will not be updated to the requested version of the newer angular package and settings/options configurations will not be updated for the new version that request them in a specific way.... these are only some that I have in my mind right now, but I bet there are more...

Comment: Even with NPM cache clean? It's kind of strange.

Comment: If you update package manually in `package.json` and then run `npm install`, this means that `package-locks.json` will be written because of your manual update. I dont know how big is your project but normally this is not something you want. Have in mind that `package-lock.json` is what holds the exact functional dependency tree of project, not `package.json`. If i were to do what you want i would 1. `manually update package 2`. `Delete package-lock.json` 3. `run npm install to generate package-lock.json` again 4. `run npm ci`, this will fire error if newly generated dependency tree is not ok

Comment: It's possible to use the update command for private registry. Also updating manually should be fine for patch and minor version. For major version, you'd need to make sure to manually update anything that might have changed. It's way easier with the command to automatically migrate code.